# match at least 5 number position at same place in given mobile number

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Given that I have the following phone number:

- 9904773779

I would like to search my data base for other phone numbers which have a least 5 digits in common with the above number, like those:

- **99**33**7**2**3**98**9**
- **9**4**0**3**7**9**3**3**7**8

My first though was to use a query like this:

```
select mobileno from tbl_registration where mobileno like '%MyTextBox Value%'
```

however, this didn't not work.

Comment: i have tried using mysql like "select mobileno from tbl_registration where mobileno like '%MyTextBox Value%'"

Comment: This sounds like you want to do something very similar to calculating [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Is this what you want? It should be noted that PHP [has a function to calculate this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) in the standard library.

Comment: i dont know about Levenshtein distance i think my question is very simple to understand

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for, a PHP solution or a MySQL solution?

Comment: any will work regular expression will also do

Comment: Well... If the numbers are stored in a table you will probably need a MySQL solution. (You can use Regexes in MySQL as well). Otherwise you'd need to get the whole table, loop through them all and then compare.. Please add the MySQL tag so this question gets attention from mysql users as well.

Comment: IMHO regex isn't a viable solution. I also can't imagine a pure MySQL solution but I'm open to be astonished. I would go for the pure PHP solution: create a function that compares two strings, a simple loop that compares each digit and keep a small counter.

Comment: Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/1DyLNF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a tidier PHP solution here is using [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php):

> This calculates the similarity between two strings.

Sample demo:

```
$numbers = array("1234567890", "9933723989", "9403793378");
$key = "9904773779";
foreach ($numbers as $k) {           
  if (similar_text($key, $k) >= 5) { // There must be 5+ similarities
    echo $k . PHP_EOL;  
  }
}
```

Output: `[ 9933723989, 9403793378]`

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ugqphD)

Comment: similar_text is definitely it. I compared similar_text to my example and the levenshtein and its definitely the fastest. https://ideone.com/hczC6T

Comment: `echo similar_text("123456", "712345");` = 5 -- I thought the OP wanted the matching numbers to be in the _same_ columns.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would go with PHP, although not very tidy and there is probably a better way.

```
<?php
$strOne = '9904773779';
$strTwo = '9933723989';
$arrOne = str_split($strOne);
$arrTwo = str_split($strTwo);
$arrIntersection = array_intersect($arrOne,$arrTwo);
$count=0;
foreach ($arrIntersection as $key => $value) {
  if ($arrOne[$key] === $arrTwo[$key]) {
    $count++;
  }
}
print_r($count);
?>
```

In the first stage I split the strings to arrays. I then use array_intersect to identify duplicate values and save them into an array. this saves having to loop through every number. I then loop thru the array of identical values and compare both arrays to see if the values are identical.

I do however look forward to a cooler answer.